# how to find out the least busy GPU in nvenc?

Tags: nvenc

I'm working on support multiple GPUs with nvenc lib in my C project. I'd like to find the least busy gpu and use it for the next encoder session. Is there an API to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:  `nvidia-smi dmon` command with -i key for target a specific GPU. And compare encoder usage for all GPUs. It's the 7th column.
Please try the following command for first GPU:

> nvidia-smi dmon -i 0 | awk {'print $7'}